# Installing Haskell on a Windows network

Tags: haskell, windows-installer, installation

I'm a teacher of Computing and we need to install Haskell on lots of Windows machines on our network. What would be a reasonable way of doing that? In particular, an MSI would be a satisfactory method, and so it would be useful to know whether anything of the sort already exists before we go through the process of making an MSI ourselves.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know what an MSI is (like many Haskellers, I'm all on Linux), but apparently the [Stack installer for Windows](https://www.stackage.org/stack/windows-x86_64-installer) works easy enough.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your question rather radically so that its closure becomes less likely. (Questions whose main purpose is asking outright for recommendations of libraries, installers and other tools are off-topic in Stack Overflow.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic because it is a question about system administration.

Comment: @immibis While the task described is one of system administration, its goal is [installing a programming environment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269596/2751851). That the question is primarily about such an environment is, I believe, enough to tilt the balance towards on-topic, at least from this perspective.

Comment: If you teach CS, you may be interested in the new [CS Educator's Stack Exchange](http://cseducators.stackexchange.com) (though since it's still in private beta, it's easiest to enter [through here](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92460/computer-science-educators))